# Retrieving a list of tuples with the Scala anorm stream API

Tags: scala, playframework, tuples, scala-collections

When I read in the Play! docs I find a way to parse the result to a List[(String, String)]

Like this:

```
// Create an SQL query
val selectCountries = SQL("Select * from Country")

// Transform the resulting Stream[Row] as a List[(String,String)]
val countries = selectCountries().map(row => 
row[String]("code") -> row[String]("name")
).toList
```

I want to do this, but my tuple will contain more data.

I'm doing like this:

```
val getObjects = SQL("SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g FROM table")
  val objects = getObjects().map(row =>
    row[Long]("a") -> row[Long]("b") -> row[Long]("c") -> row[String]("d") -> row[Long]("e") -> row[Long]("f") -> row[String]("g")).toList
```

Each tuple I get will be in this format, ofcourse, thats what I'm asking for in the code above:

```
((((((Long, Long), Long), String), Long), Long), String)
```

But I want this:

```
(Long, Long, Long, String, Long, Long, String)
```

What I'm asking is how should I parse the result to generate a tuple like the last one above. I want to do like they do in the documentation to List[(String, String)] but with more data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `((((((Long, Long), Long), String), Long), Long), String)` because of `->`, each call to this wraps two elements into a pair. So with each `->` you got a tuple, then you took this tuple and made a new one, etc. You need to change arrow with a comma and wrap into `()`:

```
val objects = getObjects().map(row =>
    (row[Long]("a"), row[Long]("b"), ..., row[String]("g")).toList
```

But remember that currently tuples can have no more then 22 elements in it.

Comment: I know that the `->` is what makes like that and I tried with the `,` instead without luck. But I see now that you've added `(` and `)` and I didnt. Will try that out right away!

Comment: Thanks @Alexlv, I had missed the `(` and `)`. Feels silly to miss such a small thing.